# Mimicking multiple class instantiations in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle

Suppose, there is a datatype with several ordering variants that could be used to specify an instantiation of a class, `partial_order` in the example below:

```
theory X imports "HOL-Lattice.Orders" begin

    datatype X = A | B | C

    definition poA :: "X ⇒ X ⇒ bool" where [iff]: "poA x y ⟷ x = y ∨ y = A"
    definition poB :: "X ⇒ X ⇒ bool" where [iff]: "poB x y ⟷ x = y ∨ y = B"
    definition poC :: "X ⇒ X ⇒ bool" where [iff]: "poC x y ⟷ x = y ∨ y = C"

    instantiation X :: partial_order begin
        definition [iff]: "leq = poA"
        instance proof qed auto
    end

    value "(A, B) ⊑ (A, B)"

end
```

Later, the information about instantiation could be used to check formulas that expect the specified class. An example of this machinery is `value "(A, B) ⊑ (A, B)"` that evaluates to `True` because type `prod` is an instance of `partial_order` as soon as both parameters are instances of this class as well.

Instead of `poA`, one could have used `poB` or `poC` to define `leq`. However, there is a restriction on class instantiations that forbids having multiple instantiations of the same class for the same type in the same theory. In order words, there is no way to have another `instantiation X :: partial_order` in addition to the given one. So, it looks problematic to specify different versions of `leq` of class `partial_order` for the same type `X`.

How does one specify that the automatically derived relation `⊑` for `(X, X) prod` should be using `poA` to compare its first parameter and `poB` to compare its second parameter?